# How to get parent of parent .... index in jquery?

Tags: jquery, traversal

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="tab_view">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab_view">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab_view">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div class="btn">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is code

```
var idx = $(this).closest(".tab_view").index();
```

I want to get [.tab_view]'s index number by click [.btn]

and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: No html found in your question.

Comment: Share the click event as well.

Comment: that should work. what is the issue?

Comment: Its working fine.. I dont find any issue...

Comment: check if you don't have any js error or find if you have referenced the jquery library.

Comment: Right Click on browser -> Inspect Element. Check the console tab

Comment: Thank you for answer TT.
BTW, it's hard to make simple of my code.
Later, change my question.

Answer (score 0):

that should work, depends on how you use it still, do you mean something like [this? CodePen here](http://codepen.io/ZetCoby/pen/Eaddzb)

```
var id = "";
$('.btn').each(function(){
  id += $(this).closest(".tab_view").index()+", ";
});
$('body').text(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

So simple put bellow code in your script code and do little bit changes into your html code.

```
jquery :  
        $(document).ready(function (e){
           $(document).on("click",".btn",function (e){
              var ind = $(this).parent().parent().parent().index();
              alert(ind);
           });
        });

HTML : 
      <div class="tab_view">
         <div>
            <div>
               <div class="btn"> 1 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>

     <div class="tab_view">
        <div>
           <div>
              <div class="btn"> 2 </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <div class="tab_view">
        <div>
           <div>
              <div class="btn"> 3  </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

click on either 1,2,3 it will give you current index number of the tab_view class you can also see the updated code of yours in JSFiddle link is "https://jsfiddle.net/jkLc1vy8/"

i hope it will help you.